# Read JSON variable in Shell Script

Tags: json, shell

How can I read a JSON variable in shell script ( to be noted "JSON variable " and not JSON File)? 
I have tried something like,

```
temp={\"name\":\"Sipdy\",\"time\":\"17:09 1985\",\"place\":\"CA\"}
jq '.time' $temp
```

and also tried

```
temp={"name":"Sipdy","time":"17:09 1985","place":"CA"}
jq '.time' $temp
```

but both the above commands expect a JSON file name in place of "$temp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the JSON text as jq's standard input:

```
$ temp='{"name":"Sipdy","time":"17:09 1985","place":"CA"}'
$ echo $temp | jq .time                                   
"17:09 1985"
$ jq .time <<< $temp
"17:09 1985"
```

(The second form is a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings).)