# How to read json objects in shell/bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting,
I want to read a json variable's attribute values,
I have a sample json like -

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "jhonny",
    "cities": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "KL"
    }],
    "otherinfo": {
        "hobby": "reading",
        "nickname": "john"
    }
}
```

**I tried the following script -**

```
#!/bin/bash

temp='{"userId":1,"name":"jhonny","cities":[{"id":1,"name":"KL"}],"otherinfo":{"hobby":"reading","nickname":"john"}}'

echo $temp | jq .name
```

I get a `test.sh: line 4: jq: command not found`
I am following this -
[Read JSON variable in Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291536/read-json-variable-in-shell-script)

Can someone help how I could extract `cities[0].name` and `otherinfo.nickname` from the shell variable?

Comment: Did you install jq? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Is it possible with any installation? I just tried that answer but didn’t know it required installation

Comment: I don't know. Can you please check the website? I learned today that this is sed for JSON data basically, but is not a standard tool of course which will be pre-installed with your OS.

Comment: `jq` uses `yq`, so you will also need to install that too.

Comment: Any pure bash/shell solution? Want to avoid installations :/

Comment: If you're working with json, you need a tool that understands the format, like jq.

Comment: Sure, but this will involve reinventing the wheel. But sure you can. Look into sed/awk.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Note that the duplicate I closed this with includes answers that use Python rather than jq. Any answer that *doesn't* use a tool (like Python or jq) with a conformant JSON parser should be avoided.

Comment: @stephanmg, ...please don't encourage folks -- reinventions of that wheel pretty much always end up getting the corner cases wrong, thus resulting in brittle systems that fail whenever data changes in unanticipated ways. [The canonical response to folks trying to do regex-based "parsing" of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14122) comes to mind.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, you are right. It is of course not advised to parse HTML with regex. I'm sorry I did not want to mislead somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON module is a standard part of Python3, so if you don't want to install `jq`, you could maybe use Python:

```
python3 -c 'import json,sys;JSON=json.load(sys.stdin);print(JSON["cities"][0]["name"]);print(JSON["otherinfo"]["nickname"]);' < data.json
```

**Sample Output**

```
KL
john
```

That assumes your JSON data is in a file called `data.json`. If it's in a shell variable called `JSON`, omit the `< data.json` from the end and use:

```
echo "$JSON" | python3 -c ...
```